# HTML5 Web SQL keeps making duplicates and breaks the old database

Tags: html, safari, webkit, web-sql

I'm making a database application for Safari purely. So I'm following this guide made by Apple: [Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/UsingtheJavascriptDatabase/UsingtheJavascriptDatabase.html).

I have made this "class" prototype so far. It works, but it keeps making duplicates of the database (they just keep stacking up in the Safari Inspector tool) (without me changing the version from 1.0):

```
function Database() {
    this.DB = null;
    this.shortName = 'gamedb';
    this.version = '1.0';
    this.displayName = 'Database';
    this.maxSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024;

    init: (function() {

    })

    this.initDB = function() {
        try {
            if (!window.openDatabase) {
                alert('Error: Databases are not supported.');
            }
            else {
                this.DB = openDatabase(this.shortName, this.version, this.displayName, this.maxSize);
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch(e) {
            if (e == 2) {
                // Version number mismatch.
                console.log("Error: Invalid database version.");
            }
            else {
                console.log("Error: Unknown, " + e + ".");
            }

            return;
        }
    }

    this.query = function(query) {
        if (query == undefined) {
            query = '';
        }

        query = query + ';'; // Add the ending semi-colon

        this.DB.transaction(
            function (transaction) {
                transaction.executeSql(
                    query,
                    [],
                    this.nullDataHandler,
                    this.errorHandler
                );
            }
        );
    }

    this.nullDataHandler = function() {
        return 0;
    }

    this.errorHandler = function(error) {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

And here's my main.js file with my jQuery handle and the instantiation of the Database prototype:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var DB = new Database();
    DB.initDB();
    DB.query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT NOT NULL)');
    DB.query('INSERT INTO users(name) VALUES ("Jackson")');
});
```

Even just blankly running this line creates duplicates:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>X</title>
    <style>
        html, body {
            background: #202020;
            color: #8d9d6a;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var shortName = 'mydatabase';
        var version = '1.0';
        var displayName = 'My Important Database';
        var maxSize = 65536; // in bytes
        var db = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Content
</body>
</html>
```

Notes:

- I have Extensions turned off
- No changes in the Developer menu (nothing disabled or blocked)

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was happening?

Comment: Sadly not. I practically dropped the whole WebSQL concept and went back to either AJAX calls with server-side scripting and/or third party libraries that fully run on it themselves instead of depending on browser-support.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in both chrome and safari. When I saved a record it would appear several times and the inspector would show duplicates of the webSQL db (50 or more!). For me it turned out that I was calling a SELECT too soon after the save in order to update the view. I moved it into a success function and that fixed the problem. I can only think that the browser gets confused and spawns multiple DBs in the inspector. This might not be the same problem but it seemed close enough to mention.

Answer (score 0):

Side information for anyone as new to this as myself.

I had a query selecting from more than one table which caused my display to duplicate. Stupid problem, simple fix by obviously selecting a single table

```
var showLearnerSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblLearnerInfo, tblDrive";// Not a great idea
var showLearnerSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblLearnerInfo; // Great idea
```